# Somewhat shady way of solving a problem from Baby Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

The problem statement is: If $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the (countably) infinite union of closed sets, show at least one of those closed sets has non empty interior.

My shady way of solving this is noting that a closed set without interior is a boundary (i.e. of some open set) and therefore has n-dimensional Lebesgue measure 0. A countable union of null sets has measure zero, so it can't be $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Is this method correct (but obviously violating the spirit of the problem as an exercise in metric topology), fundamentally wrong, or is it circular?

Comment: Oh you're right, silly me. The boundary of $\mathbb{Q} \cup [0, 1]$ has measure 1.

Comment: You may mimic the proof of Baire Category Theorem, although I believe there should be an easier way to deal with that.

Comment: In fact this problem is described by rudin as a special case of Baire's theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lebesgue measure of a boundary (of an open set) need not be zero.  Not even in $\mathbb R^1$.

Comment: Does the usual construction of a boundary with full measure hold in higher dimensions? (viz. boundary of the rationals)

Comment: We  are talking about the boundary of an open set here, not the rationals.  Correcting.

Comment: What's an example of a non-null boundary of an open set (in one and higher dimensions)?

Comment: The best example is a "fat Cantor set".  Any example $T$ in $\mathbb R$ gives example $T \times \mathbb R^{n-1}$ in $\mathbb R^n$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the countable union of closed sets each of which has empty interior.  That is, $\mathbb{R}^n = \cup_{k=1}^\infty C_k$ where each closed set $C_k$ is nowhere dense by our assumption.  But then since $\mathbb{R^n}$ is complete, this contradicts the Baire Category theorem.

Comment: The exercise was presented as a special case of the Baire theorem, so I can’t exactly use it to solve the problem.